# Python Flask Login (Validate Issues)

Tags: python, flask, authentication, sqlite

Hi I am having trouble getting my login to work. I have set up a database and done login page with a form. I added a username and password to the database but the page seems to still not be logging in.

I think something to do with the Validate. It keeps saying 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'even though the username and password are correct.

```
    completion = validate(username, password)
    if completion == False:
        error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
```

Thanks in Advance:)

I new to Python and Flask. P.S. I cant use any other libraries e.g sqlalchemy

### index.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, g
import sqlite3
import hashlib

app = Flask(__name__)

# To convert the user input password as MD5
def check_password(hashed_password, user_password):
    return hashed_password == hashlib.md5(user_password.encode()).hexdigest()   

# Takes the inputed username and passwords as arguments, and compare them against the users table
def validate(username, password):
    con = sqlite3.connect('var/data.db')
    completion = False
    with con:
                cur = con.cursor()
                cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Users")
                rows = cur.fetchall()
                for row in rows:
                    dbUser = row[1]
                    dbPass = row[2]
                    if dbUser == username:
                        completion = check_password(dbPass, password)
    return completion

def init_db():
    with app.app_context():
        con = sqlite3.connect('var/data.db')
        with app.open_resource('var/schema.sql', mode='r') as f:
            con.cursor().executescript(f.read())
        con.commit()

#The Homepage Route
@app.route("/")
def index():
  return render_template('index.html', title='Home')

#The Login Route
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        completion = validate(username, password)
        if completion == False:
            error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)


#The Dashboard Route    
@app.route('/dashboard')
def dashboard():
    #return "You have successfully logged in"
    return render_template('dashboard.html', title='Dashboard')

#The Adds to the List
@app.route('/add', methods=['GET','POST'])
def add():
  if not session.get('username'):
      abort(401)
  db = get_db()
  db.execute('INSERT INTO Bucketlist (title,day,desc) VALUES(?,?,?)', 
            [request.form['title'], request.form['day'], request.form['desc']])
  db.commit()
  flash('Your wish has been added to your list')
  return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))

#The Removes from the List
@app.route('/remove', methods=['GET'])
def remove():
  delete = request.args.get('bucket_id', '')
  print delete
  db = get_db()
  db.execute('DELETE FROM Bucketlist WHERE title=?', [delete])
  db.commit()
  cur = db.execute("select * from Bucketlist")
  row = cur.fetchall()
  flash('Your wish has been removed from your list')
  return render_template("dashboard.html",row=row)


#Logs Out The User from Their Account
@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
  session.pop('username', None)
  flash('You Have Successful Loged Out')
  return redirect(url_for('index'))


if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

### login.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

  <div class="container">
    <h1>Sign In to View Your WounderList</h1>
      <h2 class="form-text">Create Your Account Here!</h2>
<form action="/login" method="post">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" value="{{
          request.form.username }}">
         <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" value="{{
          request.form.password }}">
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Login">
      </form>
      {% if error %}
        <p class="error"><strong>Error:</strong> {{ error }}
      {% endif %}
  </div>

{% endblock %}
```

### schema.sql

```
DROP TABLE if EXISTS Users;
DROP TABLE if EXISTS Bucketlist;

CREATE TABLE Users (
    user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    username    VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password    VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Bucketlist (
    bucket_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    day DATE NOT NULL,
    desc VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    user_id INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (bucket_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id)
);
```

Comment: You should make sure to use uniform indentation in your code. Are the passwords actually stored as hashes in your database? Can you post an example user record?

Answer (score 1):

First you should know that you are not really making a "login", you are just checking a password. A login requires managing a session after the user logs in and the password is accepted.

I suspect the issue is with your password hashing so for testing purposes you should try your code without the hash. See if you can validate a plain text password first.

Secondly, it is a much better idea to just use a Flask library made for this specific purpose like `Flask-Login`, but I suppose you are a student or something.